# How can I get the value of y to equal the numbers after the operand in my calculator?

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I have gotten the display.innerHTML to store the numbers before the operand as x, and to store the operand. I am kind of stumped on a way to get the variable y to equal the numbers entered after the operand. My best guess is a sort of loop Here's the Code:

```html
<!--Coded by Brent-->
<html>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<head>
  <title>Calculator v2.0</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background: linear-gradient(blue 30%, black 50%, green 80%);
    }
    
    div.container {
      background-color: #1de4fd;
      border: 1px solid black;
      height: 210px;
      width: 195px;
    }
    
    div table tr td div {
      background-color: white;
      width: 180px;
      height: 25px;
      text-align: right;
    }
    
    button {
      height: 40px;
      width: 40px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="container">
      <table align="center">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4">
            <div id="display"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button id="one" type="button">1</button></td>
          <td><button id="two" type="button">2</button></td>
          <td><button id="three" type="button">3</button></td>
          <td><button id="divide" type="button">/</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button id="four" type="button">4</button></td>
          <td><button id="five" type="button">5</button></td>
          <td><button id="six" type="button">6</button></td>
          <td><button id="multiply" type="button">*</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button id="seven" type="button">7</button></td>
          <td><button id="eight" type="button">8</button></td>
          <td><button id="nine" type="button">9</button></td>
          <td><button id="subtract" type="button">-</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button id="zero" type="button">0</button></td>
          <td><button id="decimal" type="button">.</td>
<td><button id="add" type="button">+</button></td>
          <td><button id="equal" type="button">=</button></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var display = document.getElementById("display");
      var one = document.getElementById("one");
      var two = document.getElementById("two");
      var three = document.getElementById("three");
      var four = document.getElementById("four");
      var five = document.getElementById("five");
      var six = document.getElementById("six");
      var seven = document.getElementById("seven");
      var eight = document.getElementById("eight");
      var nine = document.getElementById("nine");
      var zero = document.getElementById("zero");
      var decimal = document.getElementById("decimal");
      var add = document.getElementById("add");
      var subtract = document.getElementById("subtract");
      var multiply = document.getElementById("multiply");
      var divide = document.getElementById("divide");
      var calculate = document.getElementById("equal");
      var op = ""; //blank op variable to be filled in when an operation button is clicked
      one.addEventListener("click", addOne);//Adding event to the button 1
      function addOne() {
        display.innerHTML += 1; //Makes the display equal to the display +1 at the end
      }
      two.addEventListener("click", addTwo);
      function addTwo() {
        display.innerHTML += 2;
      }
      three.addEventListener("click", addThree);

      function addThree() {
        display.innerHTML += 3;
      }
      four.addEventListener("click", addFour);

      function addFour() {
        display.innerHTML += 4;
      }
      five.addEventListener("click", addFive);

      function addFive() {
        display.innerHTML += 5;
      }
      six.addEventListener("click", addSix);

      function addSix() {
        display.innerHTML += 6;
      }
      seven.addEventListener("click", addSeven);

      function addSeven() {
        display.innerHTML += 7;
      }
      eight.addEventListener("click", addEight);

      function addEight() {
        display.innerHTML += 8;
      }
      nine.addEventListener("click", addNine);

      function addNine() {
        display.innerHTML += 9;
      }
      zero.addEventListener("click", addZero);

      function addZero() {
        display.innerHTML += 0;
      }
      decimal.addEventListener("click", addDecimal);

      function addDecimal() {
        display.innerHTML += '.';
      }
      add.addEventListener("click", addAdd);

      function addAdd() {
        x = display.innerHTML; //assigning the current display number as x
        op = '+'; //assigning the operator + to the variable op
        z = x + op;//possibly part of the solution I'll explain below
        display.innerHTML += op; //the display equals the displayed number + the operation 
        calculate.addEventListener("click", calc);

        function calc() { //calc function needs to have y defined this is where my question comes in
          display.innerHTML = eval(x + op + y); //work in progress calculation formula
        }
      }
      subtract.addEventListener("click", addSubtract);

      function addSubtract() {
        x = display.innerHTML;
        op = '-';
        z = x + op;
        display.innerHTML += op;//the display equals the displayed number + the operation 
        calculate.addEventListener("click", calc);

        function calc() {
          display.innerHTML = eval(x + op + y);
        }
      }
      multiply.addEventListener("click", addMultiply);

      function addMultiply() {
        x = display.innerHTML;
        op = '*';
        z = x + op;
        display.innerHTML += op;//the display equals the displayed number + the operation 
        calculate.addEventListener("click", calc);

        function calc() {
          display.innerHTML = eval(x + op + y);
        }
      }
      divide.addEventListener("click", addDivide);

      function addDivide() {
        x = display.innerHTML;
        op = '/';
        z = x + op;
        display.innerHTML += op;//the display equals the displayed number + the operation 
        calculate.addEventListener("click", calc);

        function calc() {
          display.innerHTML = eval(x + op + y);
        }
      }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

My best guess is z = x + op; to loop through the length of the two variables to only get the numbers entered after the operand. I'm just not sure on how to really incorporate the idea or if there's a better solution. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have never defined x, y and z.

Comment: @connexo x and z are (although z is never used). y however is undefined, which is what this question is asking. How to extract y from something of the form `'x<op>y'`

Comment: Yeah, z was a variable I thought would be useful in defining y so I figured I'd leave it in. Maybe give someone an idea to help with more know how than me.

Comment: Have you tried `y = display.innerHTML.replace(z, '')`? Although you might as well do `display.innerHTML = eval(display.innerHTML)` because all you're doing is reconstructing the same text.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks Nick. I been at it for a couple hours

Comment: @Brent No problem feel free to write a self answer detailing what fixed it, im on my mobile and will forget by the time I reach a PC